# How to prove that the following function is continuous at irrational numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f(x)=1$,if $x\in (\mathbb{R-Q})\cup \{0\}$,
$$f(x)=1-\frac1p, \text{ if }x= \frac np,n\in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}, p\in \mathbb{N}, \gcd(n,p)=1$$

I want to show that it is continuous at every irrational point. I was able to show that it is discontinuous at rational points through sequential criteria. But I am not able to show that it is continuous at irrational points. I think I may have to use the definition of continuity, i.e $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta \implies  |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$. But I have no clue as to how to start for it. Any hints are appreciated!

So, this is what I've tried so far:

If b is an irrational number and $\epsilon>0$, then there is $p_0\in N$ such that $1/p_0<\epsilon$. There are only a finite number of rationals with denominator less than $p_0$ in the interval $(b-1/p_0,b+1/p_0)$. Hence $\delta$ can be chosen so small that the nbd $(b-\delta,b+\delta)$ contains no rationale with denominator less than p. Then for $|x-b|<\delta$, we have$ |f(x)-f(b)|=|f(x)-1| <|f(x)|<1/p_0<\epsilon$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You're trying to show that as you get closer to an irrational number, the possible p's get larger, and as such f(x) gets closer to 1.

Comment: So, Should I take $(b-1/p,b+1/p)$ as a nbd of b?

Comment: Yes, you should use the definition, but you don't have to find $\delta$, you just have to prove there is one.  Say we ask for continuity at $x=\pi$ and set $\epsilon=10^{-6}$.  How big does $p$ have to be?  Can you argue there is an interval around $\pi$ that contains no fractions with a smaller denominator?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how can we argue that there is such an interval.

Comment: There are only finitely many fractions within $1$ of $\pi$ with a denominator smaller than $p$.  One of them is at the minimum distance from $\pi$....

Comment: Why do you take the interval $(b-1/p_0,b+1/p_0)$? We can use any bounded interval which contains $b$ in the interior.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh, it is just an interval, where $p_0\in N$. As you said we can use any interval, so I chose that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proving $f$ is continuous at irrationals.
Let $c\in\Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Q}\cup\{0\}$. If $x$ is in $\Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Q}\cup\{0\}$, then $|f(x)-f(c)|=|1-1|=0<\epsilon=\delta$.

If $x\notin\Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Q}\cup\{0\}$, then
$|f(x)-f(c)|=|1-1+\frac{1}{p}|$.

If we want $1/p<\epsilon$ then we should have $p>1/\epsilon$.

If $r=n/p$ (with $n\in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}, p\in \mathbb{N}, \gcd(n,p)=1$) with $\frac 1 p>\epsilon$, then $1\leq n<p$. Hence the set of such rational numbers contains finite elements.
That is,
$\{r_m=\frac{n_m}{ p_m}: 1\leq m\leq N\}$. Since $c $ is irrational, so  $c\neq r_m$ for $1\leq m\leq N$. Thus, $|c-r_m|>0$ for $1\leq m\leq N$.

Choose $\delta\leq\min\{|c-r_m|:1\leq m\leq N\}$.
If $|x-c|<\delta$ and $x=\frac n p$, then $p>\frac 1 \epsilon$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer my question!! Thanks

Comment: @NatashaJ You're most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof that I accept is cheating at certain level, but it works for sure-

We know that the [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) is discontinuous at rationals and continuous at irrationals. So, the negative of this function should also satisfy these same properties. So, $1$ added to the negative of this function should also satisfy these.

Since the given function is $f(x)=1-T(x)$ where $T(x)$ is the Thomae's function, $f(x)$ must be discontinuous at rationals and continuous at irrationals.

Comment: Thank you @Sayan Dutta!

Comment: @NatashaJ you're welcome :)

Comment: This is not cheating but rather reducing a given problem to another problem which is perhaps well known to many.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ah yes, sure. But, I guess this problem was given in the exercises after the main part dealt with the analysis of the Thomae's function :)

Answer (score 1):

Given an irrational number , consider the rational numbers near it. For a small enough interval around , there will be no rationals whose denominator is 1. In a smaller interval around , you can exclude rationals whose denominator is 1 or 2. Eventually, given any positive integer N, you can find a small enough interval around  containing no rationals whose denominator is ≤ N. And such intervals must in the limit become arbitrarily small, because  is irrational.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I edited my question and tried to prove what you are saying, is that proof correct?